# "No shop provided" response when calling shopify api

Tags: shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

Having some trouble with getting a list of themes in a store. I've installed a fresh version of the shopify app as shown on the shopify dev docs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I console log the response I get this:

[image]

Am I missing something obvious or important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear, from the code you have shared, what kind of `fetch` you're using.
You should use the fetch provided by the template:

```
import {useAuthenticatedFetch} from "./hooks/index.js";
const fetch = useAuthenticatedFetch();
```

which I'm reporting here to have a complete answer:

```
export function useAuthenticatedFetch() {
  const app = useAppBridge();
  const fetchFunction = authenticatedFetch(app);

  return async (uri, options) => {
    const response = await fetchFunction(uri, options);
    checkHeadersForReauthorization(response.headers, app);
    return response;
  };
}

function checkHeadersForReauthorization(headers, app) {
  if (headers.get("X-Shopify-API-Request-Failure-Reauthorize") === "1") {
    const authUrlHeader =
      headers.get("X-Shopify-API-Request-Failure-Reauthorize-Url") ||
      `/api/auth`;

    const redirect = Redirect.create(app);
    redirect.dispatch(
      Redirect.Action.REMOTE,
      authUrlHeader.startsWith("/")
        ? `https://${window.location.host}${authUrlHeader}`
        : authUrlHeader
    );
  }
}
```